# Polchinski String Theory (8.4.38) T-duality of two compactified dimensions

Tags: string-theory, compactification

I am confused about a sentence in Polchinski's String theory chapter 8 p 255 when he works out the example of the full $T$-duality with two compact dimensions. He writes

> "A simultaneous $T$-duality on $X^{24,25}$ acts as $\rho\rightarrow -1/\rho$ with $\tau$ invariant."

Here $\rho$ and $\tau$ are two complex fields that contain the four moduli $G_{24,24}, G_{24,25}, G_{25,25}$ and $B_{24,25}$.

I am not able to derive this. What am I missing?

**Details**

The start is the non-linear model
$$
S= \frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d^2\sigma \, \sqrt{g} \left[ \left(g^{ab} G_{\mu\nu}(X) + i \epsilon^{ab} B_{\mu\nu} \right)\partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X^\nu + \alpha' R \Phi(X) \right]
$$
Introduce the moduli $\rho$ and $\tau$ in (8.4.36) and (8.4.37), i.e.
$$
G_{24,24} =  \frac{\alpha' \rho_2}{R^2\tau_2}; \quad
G_{25,25} =  \frac{\alpha' \rho_2 |\tau|^2 }{R^2\tau_2} ;\quad
G_{24,25} = \frac{ \alpha' \rho_2\tau_1}{R^2\tau_2};\quad
 B_{24,25} =   \frac{\alpha'\rho_1}{R^2} 
$$
with inverse
$$
 \rho_1 = \frac{R^2}{\alpha'} B_{24,25}  ;\quad
  \rho_2 =      \frac{R^2}{\alpha'}  \sqrt{ G}   ;\quad
 \tau_1 = \frac{G_{24,25}}{G_{24,24}};\quad
 \tau_2 =  \frac{\sqrt{ G}}{ G_{24,24}}  
 $$
where $G= \det G_{mn}$.

A simultaneous $T$-duality on $X^{24,25}$ changes $R\longrightarrow \alpha' /R$ and leaves the $X$ invariant. This implies that also the $G_{mn}$ and $B_{mn}$ are invariant (I think?) and thus
$$
 \rho_1 \longrightarrow  \rho_1'=  \frac{\alpha'^2}{R^4} \rho_1;\quad
  \rho_2 \longrightarrow  \rho_2'= \frac{\alpha'^2}{R^4} \rho_2
 $$
and leaves $\tau$ unchanged. But that does not correspond to $\rho\longrightarrow -1/\rho$. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

By lack of response from anyone, let me refer to [Giveon et al. Target Space Duality in String theory, hep-th/9401139v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9401139), specifically section 2 which works out the relevant symmetries and how the moduli transform under these symmetries in detail.